# Getting correct JSON string with gson

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a java object that I need to convert to a JSON string for a restful web service input.

The String I am getting

```
{"userInfo":[{"userRef":"dummydata","docView":"dummy"}],
"searchParams":[{"dd_company":"dummy","dd_acc":"6000000","dd_serial_no":"0000","fr_amount":17779.24,"fr_doc_date":"May 4, 2015 12:00:00 AM"}],
"resultFilter":[{"sortBy":"dd_doc_d","ascending":false,"resultStart":1,"resultCount":10}]}
```

What it's supposed to look like (note that each field is separated by curly brackets as opposed to just commas on the example above)

```
{"userInfo":[{"userRef":"dummydata"},
{"docView":"dummy"}],"searchParams":[{"dd_company":"dummy"},
{"dd_acc":"6000000"},{"dd_serial_no":"0000"},
{"fr_amount":17779.24},{"fr_doc_date":"May 4, 2015 12:00:00 AM"}],
"resultFilter":[{"sortBy":"dd_doc_d"},
{"ascending":false},{"resultStart":1},
{"resultCount":10}]}
```

Basically I need each item to be separated by curly bracket within my array.

```
public class UserInfo implements Serializable {
private String userRef;
private String docView;

public String getUserRef() {
    return userRef;
}
public void setUserRef(String userRef) {
    this.userRef = userRef;
}
public String getDocView() {
    return docView;
}
public void setDocView(String docView) {
    this.docView = docView;
}

}

public class SearchParams implements Serializable{
private String cd_company;
private String fr_acc;
private String fr_serial_no;
private Double fr_amount;
private Date fr_doc_d;

public String getCd_company() {
    return cd_company;
}
public void setCd_company(String cd_company) {
    this.cd_company = cd_company;
}
public String getFr_acc() {
    return fr_acc;
}
public void setFr_acc(String fr_acc) {
    this.fr_acc = fr_acc;
}
public String getFr_serial_no() {
    return fr_serial_no;
}
public void setFr_serial_no(String fr_serial_no) {
    this.fr_serial_no = fr_serial_no;
}
public Double getFr_amount() {
    return fr_amount;
}
public void setFr_amount(Double fr_amount) {
    this.fr_amount = fr_amount;
}
public Date getFr_doc_d() {
    return fr_doc_d;
}
public void setFr_doc_d(Date fr_doc_d) {
    this.fr_doc_d = fr_doc_d;
}
}

public class ResultFilter implements Serializable{
private String sortBy;
private boolean ascending;
private int resultStart;
private int resultCount;

public String getSortBy() {
    return sortBy;
}
public void setSortBy(String sortBy) {
    this.sortBy = sortBy;
}
public boolean getAscending() {
    return ascending;
}
public void setAscending(boolean ascending) {
    this.ascending = ascending;
}
public int getResultStart() {
    return resultStart;
}
public void setResultStart(int resultStart) {
    this.resultStart = resultStart;
}
public int getResultCount() {
    return resultCount;
}
public void setResultCount(int resultCount) {
    this.resultCount = resultCount;
}
}
```

I created a gson object as below and print out the JSON String

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String chequeInput = gson.toJson(criteria);
System.out.println("JSON String: " + chequeInput);
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: what does ** mean here in your what it's supposed to look like?

Comment: I've added my POJOs for clarity

Comment: Have you tried to use: http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ You can enter your JSON and get java code representation. You can use gson.

Comment: I am using gson it's just that it's not yielding the desired string.

Answer (score 0):

The response only will come as so if you have distinct object in a collection or array for every field you want. Every get of a class will be just separate with a comma, and brackets will just appear two separate distinct position in iterable item. I think you might get what you want if you use a HashMap. But look for it better.